# How can subclass get superclass' instance variable?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

In a code below, there are 2 classes, one is Node and the other one is Btree. If split() instance is called on Node, than I would like to create new node, save it as parent, and change the Btree's root node.

How can Node access Btree.root?
Do I have to use class inheritance??
(This code is not complete code so there may be some error...although I just want to get an idea of it)

```
    Node = function(dimension,root){
        this.root = root;
        this.parent = null;
    }

    Node.prototype.split = function(
        var tmp = new Node();
        if(!this.parent){
            var soon_to_be_root = new Node();
            this.parent = soon_to_be_root;
        }
    }
    Btree = function(dimension){
        this.d = dimension;
        this.root = new Node(dimension,true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Btree is a singleton object, then:

```
var soon_to_be_root = new Node;
Btree.root = soon_to_be_root;
```

If Btree is a class and you have many instances of them, then you need to associate them. Does a Node "have a" Btree? Does a Btree "have a" Node? If either of these are correct, then you should pass the instance of one when constructing the instance of the other.

If, on the other hand, a Node "is a" Btree or a Btree "is a" Node, then inheritance is appropriate.